# Integration to Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

How to Integrate your application to Microsoft CRM 2011 using CRM 2011 SDK and C#?

Edit:
I moved my question to the answer to follow the question and answer format. according to Guido Preite.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution. Just a note, if you can keep a question/answer format, you can modify the question with few phrases describing the problem and move the content to an answer (and accept it after) it will make easier for other users that this question is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm now in a habit of sharing new things I learn everyday, I'm just gonna show here how I connected to Microsoft CRM 2011 using CRM 2011 SDK and C#. This will help you not to bang your head on the wall like I did a while ago.

First add a reference to your project to the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll. which you can get from the CRM 2011 sdk(download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004).

here is the code on how to connect to the CRM Service:

```
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

    //This is your Organization Service which you can find from the actual CRM UI. go to Settings>Customizations>Developer Resources.
    Uri organizationUri = new Uri("http://crmservername/organizationname/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"); 
    Uri homeRealmUri = null;
    ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    //Instantiate your network credential that will access the CRM Server
    credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

    OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);
    //Instantiate IOrganizationService so you can call the CRM service methods.
     IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)orgProxy

//from this you can now perform CRUD to your CRM. 
//I'm just going to provide some example on how to query your entities in CRM like so:

    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression() { };

    query.EntityName = "country";
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "2digitiso", "3digitiso");

    EntityCollection retrieved = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    foreach (var item in retrieved.Entities)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(item["name"].ToString() + " " + item["2digitiso"].ToString() + " " + item["3digitiso"].ToString());
    }
```

Reference:
http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/sample-code-for-using-iorganizationservice-in-crm-2011/ 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334708.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328149.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559599/Integrating-your-applications-with-MS-CRM-Online

In Addition if you happen to encounter a exception like this:

```
CRM Service Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
```

Install : Windows Identity Foundation (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331)

I hope I helped some of you with your project.