# Dynamics Crm 2015: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: detail

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I m trying to integrate Dynamics Crm 2015. With the help of this post, [Integration to Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212759/integration-to-microsoft-dynamic-crm-2011), I have written this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = GetCustomParameters(company.Id);
Uri uri = new Uri(parameters["serviceUrl"]);
var username = parameters["username"];
var password = parameters["password"];
var entity = parameters["entity"];
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
credentials.UserName.Password = password;

OrganizationServiceProxy osproxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(uri, null, credentials, null);
IOrganizationService _services = (IOrganizationService)osproxy;
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = entity,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("firstname", "lastname", "emailaddress")
};

EntityCollection retrieved = _services.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

When I execute this, it prompts:

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: detail

Any help would be appreciated. I don't have any previous experiences with CRM integration.

Comment: Not sure about that error, but try using [CrmConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810(v=crm.7).aspx) to connect instead.

Answer (score 0):

this QueryExpression test is made to work like CRM 2016

it's an example

```
ConditionExpression condicion1 = new ConditionExpression();
            condicion1.AttributeName = "name";
            condicion1.Operator = ConditionOperator.NotNull;

            FilterExpression filtro = new FilterExpression();
            filtro.Conditions.Add(condicion1);
            filtro.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;

            QueryExpression consulta = new QueryExpression("account");
            consulta.Criteria.AddFilter(filtro);
            consulta.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "telephone1");

            EntityCollection resultados = service.RetrieveMultiple(consulta);

            foreach (Entity c in resultados.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", c["name"].ToString(), c["telephone1"].ToString());
            }
            Console.Read();
```